# Text files containing their own name

Tags: shell-script, find, csh

I need to find in certain directory and all its' subdirectories all text files that contain their own name. How do I do this? (preferably without awk command)

Answer (score 6):

To be maximally portable and work when filenames may include spaces or other characters from `IFS`, and on systems where `find` does not handle `{}` inside quotes, use [`find -exec` in combination](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sh.html) with [`sh`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sh.html) and ordinary parameter passing:

```
find DIRECTORY -type f -exec sh -c 'grep -lFe "$(basename "$1")" "$1"' sh {} ';'
```

`find DIRECTORY -type f` enumerates all the ordinary files under `DIRECTORY` recursively. `-exec ... ';'` runs a command for each file it finds. The meat of it is the `sh` command through to `{}`, which:

- Runs the standard shell with a [script](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html) command string `grep -lFe "$(basename "$1")" "$1"` for every file matched, which:

  - Finds the base filename of the matched file (`$1`) using [command substitution](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03) and [basename](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/basename.html) - both the command substitution and the variable are quoted to account for the cases where they may contain blanks or wildcards; and
  - [`grep`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html)s the matched file (still "`$1`") for that basename, using `-l` to print only the name of the matched file. `"$1"` is quoted again to account for blanks or wildcards.
- And passes in two arguments to `sh`: "`sh`" and `{}`. `sh` is meant for the inline script's `$0` (the name of the running program, which the shell uses for error reporting for instance). `find` will replace an argument consisting exactly of `{}` with the matched filename, so the `sh` script itself gets a single argument with the full file path available as `$1`.

This will work on any POSIX-compatible system. Using `{}` inside a quoted string with `find -exec` [has implementation-defined behaviour](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html#tag_20_47_05), and so isn't portable (though it is supported by GNU `grep` and most of the BSDs) and is dangerous as the file name is interpreted *as shell code*.

Arbitrary filenames always need quoting when they may contain whitespace, wildcard characters or the value of the `IFS` input field separator variable is unknown; otherwise they will be split into multiple words and will make the program behave in unexpected ways.

---

More efficiently, you can use `find -exec` with `+` to run the minimum number of shells possible:

```
find DIRECTORY -type f -exec sh -c 'for x in "$@" ; do grep -lFe "$(basename "$x")" "$x" ; done' sh {} '+'
```

This is still portable, but provides many file paths to each execution of `sh`, so it doesn't start as many shells. Inside the shell program is a [`for` loop](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04_03) that looks at each of the files. If this is something that's going to run frequently, this is a better option than using "`;`" to terminate the command.

Answer (score 1):

```
find directoryname -type f -exec grep -l {} {} \;
```

This tells `find` to search for plain files (i.e. excluding directories, devices, symbolic links, etc.) and for each found file execute `grep` with the given parameters. `-l` instructs grep to just show the filename, not the matched line. The `{}` stands for the filename, `\;` terminates the command.

Of course you probably meant that the filename itself and not the path must be searched for. That means the directory part needs to be stripped off the first `{}` part. One solution could be:

```
find directoryname -type f -exec sh -c 'grep -l $(basename {}) {}' \;
```

For each file now a shell is started as the parameter substitution with `$( .. )` has to be done. `basename`strips off any leading directory part.

Note single quotes need to be used, otherwise the $( .. ) part will be evaluated when you enter the command, not when the shell is started by find.

Comment: Never ever embed `{}` in the _code_ argument passed to `sh`, especially  not in public Q&A websites.

Answer (score 1):

On a GNU system, you can do:

```
find . -type f -printf '%f\0%p\0' | xargs -r0n2 grep -lFe
```

(`-type f` is to restrict to *regular* files only. Change to `-xtype f` if you also want to consider symlinks to regular files).

Answer (score 0):

That worked for me:

```
find /path/ -type f -exec sh -c "grep -l \"\$(basename {})\" {}" \;

Explanation:
```

- `-type f`: find only files
- `sh -c`: execute a shell for every file
- `grep -l`: show only the file names
- `\$(basename {})`: grep for the basename

Comment: Never ever embed `{}` in the _code_ argument passed to `sh`, especially  not in public Q&A websites.

Comment: Care to explain why?

Comment: The phrase "massive security hole" probably best encapsulates the problem - a malicious (or unlucky) filename could have all sorts of fun. A file `/path/; rm -rf /` will do pretty much what you'd expect, for example, because it's just substituted literally into the code to be run.